# How to Fix Event Conflicts Between Swiper and Video.Js

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent, video.js, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper for a simple slideshow with images and videos. This works like a charm. However, because a design requirement is to have a consistent and nice looking player UI, I need to use Video.js as a video player. So I have Swiper as slideshow plugin and Video.js as video plugin. This is working except that there are event *conflicts between these two plugins*.

Swiper has a mousedown event on its root, while Video.js has a mousedown event too, on the video and its (dynamically created by Video.js) parent container. When dragging the slide (the video) not only Swiper detects that it must swipe, but also Video.js will handle this as click on the video. **Therefore if you swipe to a next slide, this always means that the video is played/paused.**

Also, when you drag the circle on the timeline Swiper also detects a swipe.

**Is there any chance to patch both event listeners to work together?** I'm searching a way without patching the libraries itself. Also the patch should not affect the original behavior of the plugins.

Here's the code I'm reffering to. You can also play with [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/h564mjqv/).

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 30
});

[...document.querySelectorAll('video')].forEach(video => {
  video.classList.add('video-js');
  video.classList.add('vjs-default-skin');
  video.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered');
  videojs(video, {
    fluid: true,
    autoplay: true
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.2.5/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.2.5/video.min.js"></script>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video preload="auto" muted loop controls>
        <source src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video preload="auto" muted loop controls>
        <source src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, but more inline with what you're asking, is to add an overlay over the video and only pass click events through to the video.

It stretches the overlay to the size of the video area whilst excluding the video control bar at the bottom.

In the `div` that that is the control bar add the class 'swiper-no-swiping' to stop video gestures from being recognised by Swiper.

Now swiping on the overlay will not cause the video to play or pause, but clicking on it will and gestures for the video control bar will be ignored by Swiper.

Of course the visible CSS and text is just to help illustrate the overlay, and would be removed.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  noSwipingClass: 'swiper-no-swiping'
});

[...document.querySelectorAll('video')].forEach(video => {
  video.classList.add('video-js');
  video.classList.add('vjs-default-skin');
  video.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered');
  videojs(video, {
    fluid: true,
    autoplay: true
  });
});

$(function() {

  var $overlay = $("#video-overlay1");
  var myPlayer = videojs('vid1');
  var $overlayArea = $("#vid1 > .vjs-text-track-display");

  // apply overlay on video to prevent swipes playing/pausing the video
  positionVideoOverlay();

  // prevent swiping action on video control bar
  $(".vjs-control-bar").addClass("swiper-no-swiping");

  $overlay.click(function() {
    if (myPlayer.paused())
      myPlayer.play();
    else
      myPlayer.pause();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    positionVideoOverlay();
  });

  function positionVideoOverlay() {
    $overlay.css("width", $overlayArea.width() + "px");
    $overlay.css("height", $overlayArea.height() + "px");
    $overlay.css("top", $overlayArea.offset().top + "px")
  }
});
```

```css
.video-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video id="vid1" preload="auto" muted loop controls>
            <source src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
      <div id="video-overlay1" class="video-overlay">Overlay that will pass clicks to video layer
        <br>But will not pass swipe gestures</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Demo illustrating the basic concept: https://jsfiddle.net/1vqozv25/4/

Comment: While this works with the actual video, it doesn't work with the video player. As you can see in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/jnjnfa2q/1/) if you position the overlaying div to overlay the video entirely, clicks on the "mute" or "fullscreen" button, or the timeline won't do anything. Also you can't drag the timeline circle like in other Video.js examples. One of the requirements was: `the patch should not affect the original behavior of the plugins.`

Comment: That's why I said "excluding the control bar at the bottom". It should only cover the area of `<div class="vjs-text-track-display">`

Comment: If you exclude the timeline from the overlay we will have the same problems like before: If you drag the circle on the timeline Swiper slides.

Comment: Edited my answer. It adds the `noSwipingClass: 'swiper-no-swiping'` class to the video control bar, and sets the height and position of the overlay. https://jsfiddle.net/1vqozv25/3/

Comment: Added code to adjust overlay when resizing the window - https://jsfiddle.net/1vqozv25/4/

Comment: The new resize improvements don't work for me: http://imgur.com/a/cKudc

Comment: You could try moving the `var $overlayArea = $("#vid1 > .vjs-text-track-display");` into the function. I wrote it more as a demo of the principles and not as final production code, so you'll need to tweak it here and there

Comment: Giving it more thought... better to set the overlay's height to be the video's height minus the control bar's height: `$("#vid1 > video").height() - $("#vid1 > .vjs-control-bar").height()`. I suspect the height of the element I had used is not accurately set by Video.js on resize. Also I wouldn't move that code into the function - it won't help at all, but will degrade performance.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a class to the option `noSwipingClass` to prevent Swiper from processing events on slides with that class. Now only the next/prev Swiper buttons will work on video slides. Perhaps a reasonable compromise.

eg.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  noSwipingClass: 'swiper-no-swiping'
});
```

with:

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-no-swiping" oncouseo>
      <video preload="auto" muted loop controls>
        <source src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-no-swiping">
      <video preload="auto" muted loop controls>
        <source src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zqhLqfck/

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait if someone else has a different approach that still allows swiping.

Answer (score 0):

This will set no swiper only for the control bar of video js.

$( ".vjs-control-bar" ).addClass('swiper-no-swiping');

Swipe still works on the video div.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Manev's answer, init Swiper with the option `noSwipingClass: 'vjs-control-bar'` would also work.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  noSwipingClass: 'vjs-control-bar'
});
```